# Different db connections for controller in multiple areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have MVC5 application which has 2 areas: area1 and area2
I'd like to access 2 different db connections per each area.
I've tried to add to 
area1\Views\web.config

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection_area1" providerName="System.data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=DB_AREA1;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

and add to 
area2\Views\web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection_area2" providerName="System.data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=DB_AREA2;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

But I am not able to retrieve DefaultConnection_area1/2 in area1/2 controllers via

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection_area1(or 2)"].ConnectionString.
```

The only thing I can access is connection string from root Web.config

Comment: Why don't you just have settings name `Area1` then `Area2` etc. asp-mvc doesn't have facilities for web.configs per area AFAIK.

Comment: I see web.config in Views, I've updated my question.

Comment: Please see the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491982/asp-net-mvc-multiple-connection-strings